# How do I modify the second element in a nested array, within an array, alone? - Ruby

Tags: ruby

So say I have a 2D array like this:

```
list = [["auburn", "http://auburn.craigslist.org"], ["birmingham", "http://bham.craigslist.org"], ["dothan", "http://dothan.craigslist.org"]]
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
list = [["auburn", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/web/"], ["birmingham", "http://bham.craigslist.org/web/"], ["dothan", "http://dothan.craigslist.org/web/"]]
```

So I have just modified the second element within each nested array.

How do I do that in Ruby?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
list.map!{|f,l| [f, l + "/web/"]}
```

Comment: This works...but another thing I am trying to do is to add another to each list element with another url modified with the ending `/bk/` for instance. So list would then be `[0] = text, [1] = url.com/web/,[2] = url.com/bk/`. How can I do that here?

Comment: This should do: `list.map!{|f,l| [f, l + "/web/", l + "/bk/"]}`

Answer (score 1):

`list.map! { |elem| [elem[0], elem[1] << '/web/'] }`

Comment: This works wonders...one question...so basically I want to capture each URL in `elem[1]` before it is modified...which I will then use as the base for another URL in `elem[2]`. How do I do that? I tried setting a local variable to be `elem[1]` before I append `/web/` to it, but it still gives me the modified URL for `elem[2]` instead of the pre-modified one. i.e. I am getting `url.com/web/` instead of just `url.com`.

Comment: This creates a new list AND modifies the existing one. If you want to modify the (strings in the) existing list, don't use `map`, just use `each`.